# How to make "msiexec /x" shortcut ask for elevation on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, wix, wix3.5

On XP (user account) when running this shortcut:

```
<Shortcut Id="UninstallStartMenuShortcut" Advertise="no"
              Name="AppName" Description="Uninstalls AppName"
              Target="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe" Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"/>
```

I'm getting an error **"You must be an Administrator to remove this application. To remove this
application, you can log on as an administrator, or contact your technical
support group for assistance."**

Why this happens instead of asking for elevation with admin password?
How can I avoid this stupid error?

Comment: Adding an Uninstall shortcut to Start menu is against Microsoft UX guidelines, by the way.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. But I guess that 99% of the users don't know that either and still expect to see it in the Start menu, that's why most of my favorite programs provide this shortcut.

http://imgur.com/gd7s2

Comment: It's true it's against UX guidelines, but if you want to do it anyways, you can do this: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/27/How-to-create-an-uninstall-shortcut-and-pass-all-the

Comment: This was needed when Windows 95 came out. Now I guess everyone knows how to install and uninstall applications in Windows. How often do you use Uninstall shortcut of your favorite programs? I think you use it rarely, otherwise they would not be your favorite programs. Then these uninstall shortcuts do nothing but clutter the Start menu.

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov, well, sometimes I do. I guess it's just a question of tastes and habits.

Comment: @Alexey, I agree with you. But as Rob says in his blog, sometimes the customer paying the bills wants it anyways so if you must do it, this is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: @lonelyass I don't know. I prefer Start menu without Uninstall. It looks as if the product *encourages* users to uninstall their app. :)

Comment: @Christopher I agree, sometimes customers or managers insist on having the shortcut in Start menu. I added Uninstall shortcut because people wanted it. However, it was an internal only benefit where you regularly install new builds of a product; in my opinion, it has much less benefit in the field where people simply use your software.

Comment: If you are uninstalling and reinstalling internally, that means your upgrade path probably isn't getting the testing that it needs. If your upgrades work, they should be able to just install the new build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Elevation" doesn't exist in XP. LUA / UAC is a Vista and beyond concept.

You could create and install an EXE that is the target of the shortcut.  This EXE could then determine if higher priviledges are needed and ask for the username and password to run the uninstall as.

Comment: I believe this is the most practical answer to my question.
Still, I'm sort of disappointed that I can't create "runas" shortcut with WiX.

Comment: The underlying Windows Installer ShortCut table doesn't expose this.  If you know a way to do it in code you could bypass the Shortcut table/element and write a custom action.  I'm not sure I see the value in it though and the risk is a fragile installer.

Comment: @lonelyass Why can't you? What stops you? You can create "runas" shortcut with WiX, but "runas" behaves differently in Windows XP — it *always* prompts for user credentials.

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov, can you provide an example of how to create "runas" shortcut from .wxs file? And yes, I know about the "runas" behavior in Windows XP. That's why the accepted solution is the most correct one.

Comment: @lonelyass Just add `runas` before the command line. `Target="[SystemFolder]runas.exe"`; `Arguments="&quot;[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe /x [ProductCode]&quot;"/>`. Yet I guess this will show a console window.

Answer (score 4):

Only administrators can install (and uninstall) applications. Therefore it makes sense that the user doesn't have permission to uninstall the software previously installed by the administrator.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense that it DOES NOT PROMPT, just throws an error. It's especially stupid because user is able to INSTALL (writing the admin pass in a prompt), but is unable to conveniently UNINSTALL.
Back in time, when I was using VS2010 setup project I just created the shortcuts with custom action and set the "runas" verb on them, so I didn't have any problems. WiX shortcuts don't support this, so now I don't know what to do.

Comment: It doesn't prompt because it isn't Vista, it's XP.

Answer (score 0):

`runas` allows you to run programs as a different user.